# Git - submodule, keep track of what submodule commit to use

Tags: git, git-submodules

Where does the "super"-repo keep track of what commit each submodule is at?

I dont see any of that info in .gitmodules

What I want to achieve is if I tag the "super"-repo, with say `1.0-alpha`, then it will remember at what commit all the submodules was at that time, so when I checkout that tag later, I'll get the submodules at their correct commit position aswell.

Is this possible without manually writing down the commit-position for each submodule?

I now realize I can get that info later on by using:

```
git ls-tree <tag>
```

But then I'll have to go into each submodule and manually checkout that specific submodule at commit `abc1234`..

/David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current commit hash for a submodule is stored in the tree object(s) associated with the commit in the master project. If you do a `git ls-tree -r HEAD` in your master project, each submodule is represented by a line of the form:

```
160000 commit <hash> <path/to/submodule>
```

This line indicates the commit in the submodule that should be checked out to match the commit in the master repository.

Comment: thats kinds of what I said in the questions... but this means that if i want to go back to a tag, and have it working with the submodules it included, I have to manually go into those  submodules and reset them to whatever commit they were at when the "super"-project was tagged?

Comment: No, after you do `git checkout whatever` in your master project, you run `git submodule update`, and it will look at the commit in your master project, and checkout whatever is needed in the submodule(s).

Comment: Thanks.. After switching between branches, this is what I forgot to do to get the appropriate submodule version! Do you know where that information is saved (at which commit the submodule is)?

Comment: The commit that the submodule currently has checked out is stored in the `HEAD` ref in the git directory associated with that submodule, which depends on your version of git. It used to be in `path/to/submodule/.git`, but newer versions disassociated the git-dir and the work tree for submodules, so now it lives at `.git/modules/path/to/submodule` in the main repository instead...